# How do I install multiple Windows Updates in one package?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, updates

I downloaded every update from Windows Catalog since XP's SP3. I would like to install them in one package. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

In a one-liner that will work right from the command line, this should work:

```
FOR /R C:\Patches %a IN (*.exe) DO %a -q -norestart
```

The "**FOR /R**" command will recursively run through everything in the "**C:\Patches**" folder and subfoldersthen match all "***.exe**" files and then execute them (the "**%a**" part) with the "**-q -norestart**" command switches.

If you want to put this in a batch file for later, you have to escape the "%" signs in the command with another "%" sign like this:

```
FOR /R C:\Patches %%a IN (*.exe) DO %%a -q -norestart
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this article from Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296861) describes what you want. You can install the patches at once with only one reboot using a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PATHTOFIXES=E:\hotfix

%PATHTOFIXES%\Q123456_w2k_sp4_x86.exe /Z /M
%PATHTOFIXES%\Q123321_w2k_sp4_x86.exe /Z /M
%PATHTOFIXES%\Q123789_w2k_sp4_x86.exe /Z /M
```

There are certain exceptions to updates before December 2002, but I don't that applies to any of the SP3 updates.

Comment: I've come across that article. The problem is you have to specify each update by name. I have hundreds of updates. I mean if there's no other way, fine, but I'd really like to avoid specifying hundreds one by one.

The switches are also out of date. It's actually -q -norestart (-q being silent).

Comment: @BrendanLong You could use a batch file to do `dir > list.txt` to get the filenames if you don't want to type it out.

Comment: not exactly what you ask but maybe worth a look: http://www.wsusoffline.net/ - the tool allows you to build packages for offline updating.